# How to get ko.computed or ko.observable underlying function in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I am creating `ko.observable` on viewModel that controls visibility of validation summary.

`PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible = ko.observable(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active");`

There's a button `finish audit` that sets the value in underlying storage to active for that `bcInStoreVisit` I have tested setting mechanism and it works ok.

error state variable `PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState()` on subsequent visits to the page works fine too.

Now the weird part: After validation value has been activated before I refresh the page If I call from chrome console `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible` it returns `false` but if I call underlying javascript `ko.observable(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active"` it returns `true`.  `getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id())` has been put in there so that validation would appear immediately (Screenshot below).

[image]

This would imply that `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible` is subscribed to something else.

**Is there a way to check to what underlying javascript under `ko.observable` is subscribed too?**
In other words how to get `ko.observable(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active"` from `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible`?

**Update:** I have looked at `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible._subscribers` there are 3 for `change` event they all look identical and none of them look like `(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active"`

**Update 2**: Event firing sequence.

```
if (hasAllDatasources) {
            if (isPopulatingForFirstTime) {
                $(bc).OnTheMoveBCTrigger('OnPreUIUpdate', [promises]);
                $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
                    var eventPromise = $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).OnTheMoveTrigger('OnPreRender');
                        eventPromise.then(function () {
                            onTheMove.applyKOBindings();
                            invokeMethodsFromQueryString();
                            $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).OnTheMoveTrigger('OnRender');
                        });
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you want to use a `ko.computed`, not a `ko.observable`. As it is you're just initializing it once.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible = ko.computed(function(){ return PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active";});` results in same behaviour `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible` is false `getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active"` is true. How can i check to what function `IsValidationVisible` has subscribed to?

Comment: I've found your question a bit difficult to follow - as a thought have you looked at knockout.validation.js? It might simplify the problem for you somewhat

Comment: @Ian Hi, no it's not `knockout.validation.js` related question, and I am not looking to rewrite validation system if that's what you are proposing.

Comment: Understand it's not using knockout.validation.js but this handles all the display of error messages when validation fails automatically, so might be a good candidate for you.

Comment: If you can simplify the problem and create a fiddle for it that demonstrates the problem, it will go a long way towards helping us help you.  Tips on creating a good SO question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> This would imply that
>   `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible` is subscribed
>   to something else.

I think you're misunderstanding what an observable is.  `IsValidationVisible` is not subscribed to anything.  Rather, being an observable, other things can subscribe to it.

Let's look at a simpler example:

```
// 1. Create foo and give it a value of "Hello"
var foo = ko.observable("Hello");

// 2. Get the value of foo and assign it to bar
var bar = ko.observable(foo());

// 3. Get the value of foo and assign it to baz
var tmp = foo();
var baz = ko.observable(tmp);
```

Please note that #2 and #3 are doing the exact same thing. Also, note that in all 3 of these examples, nothing is subscribed to anything else.

Let's change foo and see what happens

```
foo("Goodbye");
// After that, foo() will return "Goodbye"
// and bar() will return "Hello" - bar was set to "Hello" earlier and hasn't changed
// and baz() will return "Hello" - baz was set to "Hello" earlier and hasn't changed
```

So you want a subscription?  Here is how we can subscribe to something:

```
var bat = ko.computed(function() {
  return foo() + " World!";
});

// If you call bat(), you'll see "Hello World!"

// Let's change foo
foo("Adios");

// Now if you call bat(), you'll see "Adios World!"
```

With your code, you could set up `IsValidationVisible` to automatically update when the observables inside it by creating a computed like this:

```
PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible = ko.computed(function() {
  return PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" ||
    getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active";
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have tried it already, you can see identical code in second comment from the top on original question. I don't think there's a problem with writing it as `ko.observable(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.ErrorState() == "Active" || getErrorState(PageObj.bcInStoreVisit()[0].Fields.Id()) == "Active"` as it get's `eval()`'d, and question is really more about how to see what will be passed to `eval()` function, as I have solved this problem by simply setting it to `PageObj.bcInStoreActivityWithVisits.IsValidationVisible == ko.computed(false);` before page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

I looked a little more closely at the code in your screenshot and I think I see another problem.  I'll trim down the code to try to make it more concise.

```
$(inStoreActivity).on('OnPreUIUpdate', function() {
  PageObj.IsAllRequiredActivitiesDone = ko.computed(function() { ... });
  PageObj.IsAllOptionalActivitiesDone = ko.computed(function() { ... });

  PageObj.IsValidationVisible = ko.observable(...big calculation...)

});
```

Here is what I'm seeing:

1. Somewhere else you initally created 3 variables as computed / observables on the PageObj object (`IsAllRequiredActivitiesDone, IsAllOptionalActivitiesDone, IsValidationVisible`)
2. Somewhere else you called `ko.applyBindings(...)` to bind your DOM to PageObj (and all of the stuff inside PageObj)
3. When the OnPreUIUpdate event fires, you are trying to update these three things, as seen in the code just above

(If I'm wrong in my assumptions on points 1 and 2, please provide code to show me what I'm missing)

First, lets look at the `IsValidationVisible` observable.

You sucessfully create the observable, assign it a value, and bind it to the DOM.  However, you are not updating the observable in the correct way.  Because you are calling `ko.observable(...)` inside this event handler, a new observable is created every time the event fires.  However, none of these new observables are bound to the DOM (they didn't exist when you called ko.applyBindings).

Here is how you can correctly update `IsValidationVisible` inside your event handler:

```
// This is good - this is how to update an observable
PageObj.IsValidationVisible(...big calculation...);

// This is bad - DON'T UPDATE AN OBSERVABLE THIS WAY
PageObj.IsValidationVisible = ko.observable(...big calculation...)
```

Second, let's consider the computed properties.

The idea of a computed is that it's automatically run whenever observables that are used by the computed update.  So you just define the computed once and you're done.

What you are doing in your code is creating a new computed every time the event fires, and, similar to what I mentioned about the observable just above, only the initial computed you created will be bound to the DOM, so the new computeds you create aren't doing anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting so much effort into this. `OnPreUIUpdate` is not the best name for the event, I am certain it is being called only once per page load, so it should only be bound once. I have added mechanism that triggers to the question (update 2). As you can see `ko.applyBindings` is called after `OnPreUIUpdate`, and I am not rebinding it after, and `PageObj.IsValidationVisible` is initialized there for the first time.

Comment: I'm starting to get more and more lost in the complexity of the code.  Can you simplify the problem such that it can be reproduced in a fiddle?  That would help a great deal.  One other note - in looking at your code, it feels like you are fighting against knockout rather than working with it.  I see observables created in side of event handlers, and I see lots of jquery calls made outside of custom binding handlers, and both of these contribute to the complexity of the problem because it's working against the way that knockout is designed to work.